# react-native-google-autocomplete restrict result to location and radius

Tags: react-native

Can someone explain to me how to restrict results to a radius around a location please?

Using **react-native-google-autocomplete** : 
https://github.com/EQuimper/react-native-google-autocomplete

I tried to add it various places in my code but the locationResults aren't filtered any ways.

I found some resources on the official documentation but since I'm already using this library I wish to keep it for now

Should I use components, props ?
For now i'm restricting result adding the city at the end of the user input but it's very limited and ugly ^^

Hope you'll find time to answer me,
Best regards

my code below :

```
<GoogleAutoComplete 
    apiKey="*****"
    debounce={500}
    predefinedPlaces={notLocatedPlace}
    minLength={4}
    language="fr"
    components="country:fr"
    // location={{lat:45.526298,lng: 4.873333}}
    // radius={"20000"}
>
    {({ 
        handleTextChange, 
        locationResults, 
        fetchDetails, 
        isSearching, 
        inputValue, 
        clearSearchs,
        // location,
        // radius,
    }) => (
        <React.Fragment>
            {console.log('locationResults', locationResults)}
            <View 
                style={styles.adressContainer}
                // style={{flexDirection:"row", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center"}}
            >
                <TextInput 
                    underlineColorAndroid="#dfdfdf"
                    placeholder="Rechercher une adresse"
                    onChangeText={handleTextChange}
                    value={inputValue}
                    style={styles.streetInput}

                />
                {/* <Button 
                    title="clear" 
                    onPress={clearSearchs} 
                    style={styles.streetNumberInput}
                    // color="#aaa"
                /> */}
            </View>
            {isSearching && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#1faadb" />}
            <ScrollView>
                {locationResults.map(el =>(
                    <LocationResultItem 
                        {...el}
                        key={el.id.toString()}
                        fetchDetails={fetchDetails}
                        {...{clearSearchs}}
                        // query={{
                        //     location: '45.526298, 4.873333',
                        //     radius: '15000', //15 km
                        //     strictbounds: true,
                        // }}
                    />
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
            {/* <Text></Text> details a importer 2 way binding*/}
        </React.Fragment>
    )}
</GoogleAutoComplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

You can add the parameters `location` and `radius` to the `query` object. This works for me:

```
query={{
  key: appConfig.googleAPIKEY,
  language: "de",
  components: "country:de",
  strictbounds: true,
  location: "30.5324, 3.23234",
  radius: "15000", // 15 km
}}
```

Got the solution from this [discussion](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues/275).